# How to dynamically override Docker's 'containerRegistry' attribute in Azure Pipeline?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops

In my Azure Build Pipeline, I'm trying to override the container registry to push the Docker image depending on the environment I'm deploying to. To do so, I created a variable which is given a value in a PowerShell script (i.e. the environment to which I deploy). After that, I use that variable to override the container registry in a Docker step.

The problem is, even though the variable is correctly set, the container registry isn't overridden. So the Docker step uses the default registry which is not recognized as a service connection in Azure DevOps.

Here are the concerned steps in azure-pipeline.yml and the output of Docker Push step:

PowerShell script to calculate $registry variable

```
- powershell:
    if( $env:BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME.Equals("develop") )
    {
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=registry]Docker Dev";
    }
    elseif ( $env:BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME.Contains("release") )
    {
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=registry]Docker Staging";
    }
  displayName: 'Set environment configuration'
```

Docker push step

```
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: 'push API image to azure registry'
  inputs:
    containerRegistry: '$(registry)'
    repository: 'api.admin'
    command: 'push'
    tags: '$(version)'
```

Output

```
The push refers to repository [docker.io/library/api.admin]
2dce5cb1fcef: Preparing
3dac20cd9e05: Preparing
bc6688385ca5: Preparing
e5b3b5565ba6: Preparing
41c7377e2f9c: Preparing
06b99a66c400: Preparing
13cb14c2acd3: Preparing
06b99a66c400: Waiting
13cb14c2acd3: Waiting
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
##[error]denied: requested access to the resource is denied
##[error]The process '/usr/bin/docker' failed with exit code 1
```

Do you know if there is a way to dynamically override container registry in a Docker step in an Azure Pipeline?

Comment: is it really that hard to paste the text as text?

Comment: How are you verifying that the variable is set correctly? I would advise you to get it printed to make sure it is correct.

Comment: @AnkushJain I already have a step to print it out but didn't put the screenshot for security reasons. It prints the correct value

Comment: Encountered the same issue. Azure Pipeline is very inconsitent. I have not tried others yet except git actions, but Azure Pipelines already is the worst for me. It's not even in the documentation. Chat GPT can't even answer with certainty and just assume it does not accept variable bec of security reasons. Very bad. It has to be hard-coded or as answered below. Anyways, I think you should be maintaining 1 service connection. I just wanted mine to be in variable groups, so that it can be changed in devops instead in the code.

Comment: Edit: Linking the variable group in the pipeline will work. But it defeats the purpose esp if you have 2 variable groups: for dev and prod. Coz it means you link both. I am not sure why this is the case for containerRegistry, but it behaves like a bug. A bug bec it works with variables defined in the pipeline, but not with variable group. Both are processed compile time, prior to docker login step. Weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably do something like this:

1. remove powershell script step
2. add another docker step
3. add conditions to docker steps:

```
${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/develop') }}:
docker 1 task

${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release') }}:
docker 2 task
```

this way you can basically hardcode the registry, but only execute the step that is meant for that specific branch.

```
variables:
  ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/develop') }}:
    registry: regA
  ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release') }}:
    registry: regB
```

Comment: That means I would have 10 Docker steps if I had 10 different environments. That's actually what I was trying to avoid in my pipeline

Comment: your approach will never work, because your variables are runtime and the yaml rendering is done pre-runtime, it might work if you define variables the same way, with ifs. honestly I dont see why that's an issue, you would still have the code duplication in powershell, so why do you care?